# Wait for all processes created though spawn/3 to finish and collect their results in Elixir

Tags: concurrency, elixir

I want to spawn multiple processes which would do some computation and collect the results of each in a list. Consider this, although incorrect, toy example:

```
defmodule Counter do
  def loop(items \\ [])

  def loop(items) do
    receive do
      {:append, item} ->
        IO.inspect([item | items])
        loop([item | items])
      :exit ->
        items
    end
  end

  def push(from_pid, item) do
    send(from_pid, {:append, :math.pow(item, 2)})
  end

  def run() do
    for item <- 1..10 do
      spawn(Counter, :push, [self(), item])
    end

    loop()
  end
end

Counter.run()
```

1. Method `run/1` spawns 10 processes with 2 arguments - process id and number.
2. Each spawned process computes the result (in this case, squares the given number) and send the result back.
3. Method `loop/1` listens for messages and accumulates the results into a list.

The problem is I do not understand how to properly stop listening to messages after all created processes are done. I cannot just send another message type (in this case, `:exit`) to stop calling `loop/1` recursively as some processes might not be done yet. Of course, I could keep track of the number of received messages and do not call `loop/1` again if the target count is reached. However, I doubt that it is a correct approach.

How do I implement this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is I do not understand how to properly stop listening to
> messages after all created processes are done

1. `spawn/3` returns a pid.  Keep a list of all the pids, then pass the list as an argument to your `loop()` function.
2. The receive inside your `loop()` function will wait for a message that begins with a pid.  The first pid in the list will be the first message you wait for, e.g. `{FirstPid, Result}`.
3. A spawned process should send a message back in the form of  `{self(), Result}`.
4. Once you receive a message from the first pid in the list, then you recursively call `loop()` again with the tail of the list.
5. Once the list is empty, you end your loop (think multiple function clauses).

Now, suppose the first pid takes the longest to calculate a result, so you sit there waiting in the receive for that result, thereafter all the other receives will execute with no waiting, taking a few microseconds to execute, so the total amount of time to get all the messages will be approximately equal to the time it takes for a pid to do the longest calculation.

Next, suppose the first pid takes takes the shortest time to calculate the result, say T1.  The second pid will finish its calculation in T2-T1 seconds because while you were waiting for the first pid to finish, the second pid was also calculating its result for T1 seconds, so it only needs T2-T1 seconds to complete its calculation, and so on for T3, T4, etc.  Basically, all the shorter calculations will finish before the longest calculation, and you will receive their messages before the longest calculation finishes, so the total time you wait will be the time of the longest calculation.

In other words, it doesn't matter what order the pids are in the list.

Answer (score 3):

`Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink` is a good tool for doing tasks like this.  Although this may not address the specifics of how the low-level `send` and `receive` functions work, it is a good recipe for dealing with problems like this, especially when you need to control how many things happen concurrently.

Consider the following block: it will take approx. 5 seconds to run because each task sleeps for 1 second, but we run 2 of them concurrently (via `max_concurrency`).

```
iex> Task.Supervisor.start_link(name: TmpTaskSupervisor)
iex> Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink(
        TmpTaskSupervisor,
        1..10,
        fn item ->
          IO.puts("processing item #{item}")
            Process.sleep(1_000)
        end,
        timeout: 120_000,
        max_concurrency: 2
)
|> Stream.run()
```

If you want to return the values, convert the resulting stream to a list, but keep in mind that each return value will be wrapped in an `:ok` tuple:

```
iex> Task.Supervisor.start_link(name: TmpTaskSupervisor)
iex> Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink(
        TmpTaskSupervisor,
        1..10,
        fn n ->
          n * n
        end,
        timeout: 120_000,
        max_concurrency: 2
)
|> Enum.to_list()
[ok: 1, ok: 4, ok: 9, ok: 16, ok: 25, ok: 36, ok: 49, ok: 64, ok: 81, ok: 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Flow](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/):

```elixir
1..10
|> Flow.from_enumerable(max_demand: 1)
|> Flow.map(&(&1 * &1))
|> Enum.to_list()
```

Result (unsorted):

```elixir
[1, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 4, 64, 81, 100]
```